# EclipseLink - NullPointerException on checkForUnregisteredExistingObject

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I got an strange exception on inserting new objects into a database using eclipseLink.

I have a class called 'Log' which is the entity class for my database table 'LOG'.

```
@Entity
@Cache(isolation = CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)
@Table(name = "LOG")
@XmlRootElement

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Log.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM log f")})

public class Log implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "L_ID")
    private Long lId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeTimestampConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "L_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime lDate;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "L_MESSAGE")
    private String lMessage;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "L_R_ID", referencedColumnName = "R_ID")
    private Receipt lrId;
    @Transient
    private Details det;

    public Log(Message m) {
        this.lDate = m.getDate();
        this.lMessage = m.getMessage();
        this.lrId = m.getReceipt();
        this.det = m.getDetails();
    }

    //access methods

}
```

I create a new object of that class by passing an existing object of the class 'Message' (POJO). Then I call the persisting method in the facade.

```
public static void log(Message m) {
    LogFacade logFacade = EjbUtil.lookup(LogFacade.class); //Injection doesn't work under given conditions
    Log l = new Log(m);
    logFacade.createLog(l);
}
```

Method for persisting using the facade:

```
static final String UNIT_NAME = "Application_PU";
@PersistenceContext(unitName = BaseEjb.UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager em;

public void createEntry(Log l) {
    em.persist(l);
}
```

And then I got this exception:

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-12-27 17:06:29.337--UnitOfWork(294989774)--java.lang.NullPointerException
[EL Warning]: transaction: 2017-12-27 17:06:29.337--UnitOfWork(294989774)--java.lang.NullPointerException
<27.12.2017 17:06 Uhr MEZ> <Error> <EJB> <BEA-010026> <Exception occurred during commit of transaction Name=[EJB my.application.database.ejb.LogFacade.createLog(my.application.database.entities.Log)],Xid=BEA1-0025F6E499E77F28EDB9(2091508756),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=java.lang.NullPointerException],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=30,useSecure=false,SCInfo[mydomain+myserver]=(state=rolledback),properties=({weblogic.transaction.name=[EJB my.application.database.ejb.LogFacade.createLog(my.application.database.entities.Log)]}),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=myserver+127.0.0.1:7001+mydomain+t3+ CoordinatorNonSecureURL=myserver+127.0.0.1:7001+mydomain+t3+ coordinatorSecureURL=null, XAResources={my_database, WSATGatewayRM_myserver_mydomain},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=myserver+127.0.0.1:7001+mydomain+t3+): weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Unexpected exception in beforeCompletion: sync=org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener@1bd77023
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:1985)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:369)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:260)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:338)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:207)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:46)
        at my.application.database.ejb.LogFacade_kxnnu4_NoIntfViewImpl.createLog(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried inserting the object by using eclipseLink's persist operation directly:

```
static final String UNIT_NAME = "Application_PU";
@PersistenceContext(unitName = BaseEjb.UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager em;

public void createEntry(Log l) {
    em.persist(l);
    em.flush();
    getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Log.class);
}
```

Then I get this exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:927)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:863)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.persistence.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.invoke(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:91)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.flush(Unknown Source)
```

The exception text seems to describe the problem very clearly. But I have no idea, how to fix it. And it seems to be really strange, because it's working with other objects and their classes.

The application is running on a Weblogic 12c, using an Oracle database.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have wired `EntityManager em` and you are using `getEntityManager()`!!

Comment: In the application is a basic ejb class used, which encapsulates the entity manager for all ejbs. I fixed it in the post to make it more clear. Please describe more clearly what looks weired to you.

Comment: Flush is trying to traverse objects registered within the EM context, and is encountering a problem with an object referenced on one of your mappings. This could be any Entity within the EntityManager, not just the Log graph passed to the createEntry method, but I'd start by looking at what is in the Log. lrId reference. EclipseLink cannot find a descriptor/mappings for an object referenced in a mapping. My guess is that this could be caused by a class loading issue, where the referenced object was somehow loaded differently then the persistence unit.